# Stata: Creating graphs in loop with changing titles, longitudinal dataset

Tags: for-loop, graph, stata

I have a longitudinal dataset in Stata and would like to create separate `tsline` graphs of each group inside a variable. So, say I have time running from 1980 to 2010 and categories 1, 2, ..., 17; I want to create seventeen separate `tsline` graphs, plotting the respective values of variable X from 1980 to 2010 and using the category label as a title.

I wrote a short loop that creates the `tsline graphs`, but I can't figure out how to add the correct title. The title should be label of the value of the categorical variable. That is, if I plot X for `ID == 1`, I want the title to be the label of `ID == 1`, if that is possible. Ideally, I would like to store a specific value label as `local` for each `` `i' `` in the loop. That way I could also use it also as part of the file name when exporting graphs, example given.

My code:

```
tsset ID Date, daily

forvalues i = 1/17 {
tsline X if ID==`i', title(??)
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use *extended macro functions*. Here is one example:

```
clear all
set more off

sysuse auto

forvalues i = 0/1 {
    local t : label origin `i'
    display "`t'"
    twoway scatter mpg weight if foreign == `i', title("`t'")
}
```

`origin` is the name of the value label associated with the variable `foreign`. You can list the names and contents of all value labels using `label list`.

The line `` local t : label origin `i' `` retrieves the label for the value in macro `i`, and assigns it to the macro `t`. Then you can use macro `t` as you wish.

See `help label`, `help macro` and `help extended_fcn`.

Comment: Note that syntax such as `local t: label (foreign) \`i'` removes the need to look up the name of the value label.